# How to create a link to a file on a LAN?

Tags: fstab, symbolic-link, lan, dolphin

I would like to create a link to a file on a network drive so that I can easily access the file from my computer. I have samba and can access the file using Dolphin on Kubuntu. I can make a link to it in **Places**.  I have several networked files I would like links for. So, I've created a folder to store these links and put a link to that folder in **Places**. If I drag the link in **Places** to my link folder the actual file ends up moved into the folder.

- The networked drive is mounted on `/media/user/windowsshare`
- Links are created in: `/media/user/path`

I tried a few different methods to create a link:

```
$ ln -s "smb:⁄⁄user@computer⁄path/filename.ext"
```

This created a link that when clicked gives this message:

> Unable to run the command specified.
>       The file or folder  /media/user/path/smb:⁄⁄user@computer⁄path/filename.ext does not exist.

```
$ ln -s "/media/user/windowsshare⁄path/filename.ext"
```

This created a link that when clicked gives this message:

> Unable to run the command specified.
>       The file or folder /media/user/path/windowsshare⁄path/filename.ext does not exist.

The Ctrl-Shift drag and drop method in Dolphin
makes a desktop configuration file `smb:⁄⁄user@computer⁄path/filename.ext.desktop` which doesn't point to anything and when clicked gives this message:

```
Could not enter folder smb://user@coolermaster-pc/E/Work  Files/TECH/A_Fabrication/Production_Plan-II.xls.
```

A link (in the same directory) to a local file `/media/user/path/filename.ext` works.

Comment: you should mount before you create link.  if the device isn't mounted; you'll get 'link broken' messages which will correct the moment you mount the device (inc. networked mounts).  you don't need to mount in /media; you can 'mount' anywhere (esp. if you use /etc/fstab (file system table which is my choice).  sorry I can't help with elegant (i like commands)

Comment: @chrisguiver commands are elegant when we construct them well and they do what we ask cleanly.   Some weeks ago I made this line in fstab. `//coolermaster-pc/E   /media/geoffrey/windowsshare   cifs    rw,credentials=/home/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0` Should this be doing the trick?  What should my link look like if the networked drive is mounted correctly? `smb://user@computer/path or something different?`

Comment: @guiverc I used `df` and didn't see my network drive mounted even though there was that line in _fstab_ that made it look like it should be.  I edited _.smbcredentials_ and corrected the password to the networked PC.  Now the networked drive shows mounted with `df`. In Dolphin I can create a link to the directory that the file is in.  When I create and use a link directly to the file I get: _Could not enter folder smb://user@computer/path/filename.ext_  How can I make it see it as a file and use the related program to open it?

Comment: I've never created links via gui (dolphin or other file mgr) so I don't know (and aren't will to try as I have no samba devices up; i use nfs).  i usually create the links with `ln` (I recalling have to use -s for soft-links) from term and just use `ls` to check it works, and within apps just refer to the local path  (eg. `/mnt/buf128/dir1/dir2` to access my buffalo [backup nas] device 128.  I'm used to seeing `,auto` or `,noauto` in my mount statements in /etc/fstab but that could just because I primarily use nfs (backup scripts that mount offline buf devices use commands to mount not fstab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how this happened, but you got "Fraction slash" characters (Unicode U+2044) in your filenames:

```
smb:⁄⁄user@computer⁄path/
    ^^             ^
/media/user/windowsshare⁄path/filename.ext
                        ^
```

I noticed this cause the italic double-slash in your question looked weird: *smb:⁄⁄*

Only a "Solidus" (U+2f) is a valid path delimiter, so this command should work:

```
ln -s "/media/user/windowsshare/path/filename.ext"
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you strike out the the smb code as it doesn't work.  The only reason why I can think that the slashes came out funny (created by the code) is because I use Thai on my computer.  The character set must have been set up funny.

Comment: @GeoffreyWheeler Welcome! Thanks for the suggested edit, but it had some new content I wouldn't agree with. The Super User link about different special slashes is irrelevant, since only a regular slash is valid. The `ln` command still had the wrong slash character in it, so I fixed that. But I did incorporate some ideas from it, thanks.

Comment: `n -s "/media/user/windowsshare/path/filename.ext"` created a link with fraction slashes. I don't know how fraction slashes could get in it in the first place. The title of the Super User question is slightly misleading - the answer actually covers all 3 types of slashes. I found it well written and useful - I never knew there is more than one type of slash.  It's also unfortunate but I am unable to use unicodes in my Kubuntu.  I use Compose instead when I need a special character.   I just used the keyboard / to correct the link.